# Unexpected token < in JSON using ASP.NET MVC and Angular

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, angular, typescript

I have this error, when I'm trying to return `Index` page. The data from client comes to server correctly, then I'm trying to return `Index` page and getting an error. Please, check my code, where am I wrong?

`account.service.ts`:

```
login(url: string, model: any): Observable<any> {
    let body = JSON.stringify(model);
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    return this._http.post(url, body, options)
        .map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

`account.component.ts`

```
onSubmit(formData: any) {

            this._accountService.login(Global.BASE_USER_ENDPOINT+"Account/Login", formData._value).subscribe(
                data => {
                    if (data == 1) {
                        this.msg = "Success";
                    }
                    else {
                        this.msg = "Something wrong while login";
                    }
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(this.msg);
                }
            );

}
```

And my Controller:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel login)
    {
        //...
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

Comment: Look at the response in developer tools. It probably has an error message in it.

Comment: Check Network tab in browser console, it may lead you to source of error. Probably you're returning HTML page (usually containing HTTP error) instead of JSON object.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto the error lead me to `.map((response: Response) => <any>response.json())` of `account.service.ts` file

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto you mean HTML page from server?

Comment: @V.Aliosha Right, on certain error conditions the server will send HTML page explaining the problem instead of expected JSON response. You can check with console logging to find out what HTML page has returned (possibly the response contains HTML tags).

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto as you can see in my controller, the `Login` returns an HTML page, so as I understand that is my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Controller method Login, you are returning with the statement:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

which will return an html view, whereas on the client-side, you are expecting a JSON response "`response.json()`"

You must return an `ActionResult` to your client-side `_accountService.login` method and do the redirecting action there based on your result.

Comment: RedirectToAction returns an ActionResult. I assume you mean JsonResult (or similar)?

Comment: @TiesonT. One can also return Action result as JsonResult e.g. I am using this as my method signature: `public async Task<IActionResult> GetContents` and returning my model as json result like this: `return new ObjectResult(contents);`

Comment: The point I was making is that RedirectToAction _does_ return an ActionResult (RedirectToRouteResult derives from ActionResult, as do most (all?) of the result types), so it would make sense to be more specific in that statement.